# I want to install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get - what repository should I add?

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-12.04

I want to install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get.

> apt-cache show php5-fpm

only lists *5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1* and *5.3.10-1ubuntu3*. There is a critical bug in 5.3.10 ( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61045&edit=1 ) that I am trying to avoid.

Is there a repository that will let me install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: this is a serverfault.com question

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: or even http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I use the dotdeb.org repositories.

Comment: I cant use dotdeb.org for ubuntu

Comment: dotdeb most certainly does work on ubuntu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936934/how-to-install-php-5-3-14-ubuntu-12-10

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.4 Should be Out by now.
Try updating with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Comment: if php5 is installed, this command should be used : `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead of `install`

Answer (score 1):

This question is definitely off topic but the answer is quite simple so I will post it anyway:

`sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-common`