# How to install php 5.3.14 ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php

I have to install this specific version on my ubuntu 12.10 to keep compatible with provider. 
I could install php 5.3.10 easily with synaptic, but could not upgrade to 5.3.14. 
How can i do that ? Apt-get doesnt work... I saw several tutos on the web, but nothing specific to this one.

Comment: Er.... `apt-get` doesn't work? I hope you just mean that none of your repositories offer `PHP/5.3.10`, otherwise you have a huge problem :)

Comment: by "doesn't work" i think he means php is not updates to 5.3.14... I have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Remove and purge packages:

```
apt-get remove php-apc php5 php5-mysql php5-gd php5-curl libapache2-mod-php5

apt-get autoremove
```

Make sure you understand what this command does before running it:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
```

You can usually add sources from old versions without worrying too much:

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list**

```
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

Here is a possibly too broad, but hopefully instructive apt preferences file:

**/etc/apt/preferences.d/php_precise**

```
Package: php5
Pin: release a=precise
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: php*
Pin: release a=precise
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: php-*
Pin: release a=precise
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: libapache2-mod-php5
Pin: release a=precise
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: php5
Pin: release a=precise-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: php*
Pin: release a=precise-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: php-*
Pin: release a=precise-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: libapache2-mod-php5
Pin: release a=precise-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Update and check your changes

```
apt-get update

apt-cache policy <package> to check which version will be installed (eg php5)
```

Do some test runs, you may have dependencies that you need to add to the preferences file

```
apt-get install <everything you removed before>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should override apt-get to fetch the latest version of PHP (but I think only stable, so all alpha/beta versions probably won't be installed)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
php5 -v
```

Furthermore you can update you apt preferences to never install a higher update of a package.
You can do this by opening up /etc/apt/preferences and add the following:

```
Package: php
Pin: release v=5.3.14*,a=stable,c=main,o=Debian,l=Debian
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

This is an Debian example, but Ubuntu is based on Debian and as I can't test it on a live Ubuntu distro at the moment, I think this will likely suffice.

To make this "version-blockade" work you probably first need to uninstall php through apt-get and then reinstall it so it will stick to 5.3.14.

Comment: Hey, tks VM for the answer ... but i need the 5.3.14 version for the reason above! To install the latest version is very simple ... This one is giving me trouble